# FinalClass check in Checkstyle

Tags: java, final, checkstyle

In [FinalClass](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#FinalClass) check documentation I see:

> Checks that a class which has only private constructors is declared as final.

However, there is no reasoning behind this check explained.

What's the benefit of:

```
final class Util { private Util{} }
```

over the following?

```
class Util { private Util{} }
```

I cannot subclass `Util` anyway, so I see absolutely no value added. Is there any hidden reason that I'm missing?

Comment: It makes your intentions more clear.

Comment: And beyond that, maybe the compiler / JIT can do more optimization for things that are explicitly marked **final**.

Comment: I would also think that if you delcared a class `extends Util`, it wouldn't be smart enough to notice that there are no constructors to `super` into. By forcing `final` the compiler then knows that the class can't be extended.

Comment: @Zircon _what_ wouldn't be smart enough? If you wrote `Zircon extends Util` you would get a compiler error.

Answer (score 1):

You could see the difference when You try to extend Util:

```
public class BetterUtil extends Util
```

*Error:(6, 8) java: Util() has private access in de.demo.Util*

If it is marked **final**, then no one would make this mistake.

Comment: But one cannot extend a `class` with only `private` ctors, admittedly the compiler error would be _different_ but it still wouldn't compile: "_Util() has private access in com.mypackage.Util_".